# Tag Library supports namespace

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm new using PrimeFaces, When I try to run DataView example (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataView.xhtml):

```
<p:dataView var="car" value="#{dataGridView.cars}" rows="12" paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="6,12,16"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                            gridIcon="fa fa-th-large" listIcon="fa fa-bars" >
```

I See this error:

```
<p:dataView> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: dataView
```

I'm using PrimeFaces v6.2

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's for 6.2.3 (Elite) and 6.3: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3594

Comment: Showcase normally mentioned things like this...  'since 6.2.3' right?